# Freed Memory not reflecting in DF command

Tags: linux, du, linux-disk-free

My system memory was almost full as seen by DF command

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              40G   38G  268M 100% /
udev                  2.0G   84K  2.0G   1% /dev
```

When I checked I saw one directory consuming 7 GB.

```
# du -sh /home/testuser/ccmData/
7.0G    /home/testuser/ccmData/
```

I logged in as "testuser" and freed most of the contents by "rm -rf command" and now only 200 MB data is left.

```
# du -sh /home/testuser/ccmData/*
199M    /home/testuser/ccmData/neo
4.0K    /home/testuser/ccmData/leo
```

But the freed memory is not reflected

But du and df commands are still does not reflect the freed 6 .8 GB of memory.

```
# du -sh /home/testuser/ccmData/
7.0G    /home/testuser/ccmData/

# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              40G   38G  268M 100% /
udev                  2.0G   84K  2.0G   1% /dev
```

I tried rebooting the system but no benefit.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: May be some directories and files not belong to testuser in this ccmData, then du not show this files (if it is have no access) and "rm -fr" not delete them, because of again it is have no access. try call "rm -fr" from root.

Comment: Thanks user for the suggestion.
I logged in as root and saw a .moved directory and the deleted data was  inside it. Deleted the directory and memory is freed now.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that hidden files are not globbed by default. There are still hidden file objects in `/home/testuser/ccmData` that have not been erased, hence inspecting only `/home/testuser/ccmData/*` won't find them.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for the hint.
I logged in as root and saw a .moved directory inside it. Deleted the directory and memory is freed now.